# Selecting Features By Rectangle in PyQGIS standalone

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-location, standalone

I want to select features by a rectangle in QGIS standalone using Python but the function `iface.actionSelectRectangle().trigger()` is not available in a standalone application.

How to code `iface.actionSelectRectangle().trigger()` in standalone application?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about a standalone QGIS application with a map canvas. A fairly easy way would be to use the `QgsMapToolExtent` class to draw a rectangle on the canvas, connect to its `extentChanged` signal, then select features which intersect the rectangle.

Below is a fairly minimal but still complete example:

```py
import sys
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsLayerTree, QgsVectorLayer, QgsLayerTreeModel
from qgis.gui import (QgsMapCanvas, QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge, QgsLayerTreeView,
                        QgsMapToolPan, QgsMapToolExtent)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDockWidget, QToolBar, QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class myWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.setGeometry(250, 150, 1000, 750)
        
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas(self)
        
        self.tool_bar = QToolBar('Map Tools', self)
        self.addToolBar(self.tool_bar)
        
        self.pan_action = QAction('Pan Map', self.tool_bar)
        self.pan_tool = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
        self.pan_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.canvas.setMapTool(self.pan_tool))
        self.tool_bar.addAction(self.pan_action)
        
        self.select_action = QAction('Select by Rectangle', self.tool_bar)
        self.select_tool = QgsMapToolExtent(self.canvas)
        self.select_tool.extentChanged.connect(self.get_extent)
        self.select_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.canvas.setMapTool(self.select_tool))
        self.tool_bar.addAction(self.select_action)
        
        self.clear_action = QAction('Clear Selection', self)
        self.clear_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.layer.removeSelection())
        self.tool_bar.addAction(self.clear_action)
                
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Desktop\\GIS Files\\Natural Earth Data\\ne_10m_airports\\ne_10m_airports.shp', 'Airports', 'ogr')
        
        self.layers_widget = QDockWidget('Layers', self)
        self.view = QgsLayerTreeView(self.layers_widget)
        self.root = QgsLayerTree()
        self.root.addLayer(self.layer)
        self.model = QgsLayerTreeModel(self.root)
        self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.layers_widget.setWidget(self.view)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.layers_widget)
        
        self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self.root, self.canvas)
        self.bridge.setAutoSetupOnFirstLayer(False)

        self.canvas.setExtent(self.layer.extent())
        self.canvas.zoomByFactor(1.1)
        self.canvas.refresh()
                
    def get_extent(self, rect):
        self.select_tool.clearRubberBand()
        ids = [f.id() for f in self.layer.getFeatures() if f.geometry().intersects(rect)]
        self.layer.selectByIds(ids)
        

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    qgs.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis", True)
    qgs.initQgis()
    
    w = myWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The resulting application looks like this:

[image]